# Using Jquery zClip in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, zeroclipboard, zclip

I've been looking through SO but can't seem to find an answer.  I'm trying to use zClip to add a copy button to text that pops up in a tooltip.  So, when the user clicks on the tooltip, there will be an option to quickly copy the displayed text right to their clipobard.

But I just can't seem to get the zClip flash file to find the copy button once it's in the tooltip.  I've tried adjusting the css positions and z-index's but nothing seems to work.

Here's what I posted to the developer of the qTip2 tool tip:

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/4211/

He was kind enough to respond with:

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/4256/

But I still can't get it to work.  Any ideas?  I'd be happy to try a modal window too (I believe Scribd uses zClip that way).  I tried a modal window but had the same problem.